# Show that $E[N_Y]=\frac{E[e^{-\lambda X_1}]}{1-E[e^{-\lambda X_1}]}$

Tags: probability

Let $X_n$'s be independent and nonnegative random variables. A random variable $Y$ is exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda$ and it is independent of $X_n$

Define an integer value random variable $N_Y=\max\{n|X_1+...+X_n \leqq Y\}$

If we interpret $X_i$'s as inter-arrival times of customers. then $N_Y$ is the number of arrivals within the random amount of time $Y$.

**Question** : Show that $$E[N_Y]=\frac{E[e^{-\lambda X_1}]}{1-E[e^{-\lambda X_1}]}$$

hint 1 : $P(X_1+...+X_n\leqq Y)=P(X_1<Y)^n$ (memoryless property)

hint 2 : $E[N]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(N\geqq Y)$

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem? Give it a try and follow the hints which you are given.

Comment: @saz I have tried to convert N_Y=max{N|X1+...+Xn≦Y} into P(X1<Y)^n  and set  P(X1<Y)^n into E[Y] but don`t know how to transform it to above

Comment: Please check my edit. Also I think that the $X_n$ must have *identical distribution*. That is not mentioned yet in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P\left(N_{Y}\geq n\right)=P\left(X_{1}+\cdots+X_{n}\leq Y\right)=P\left(X_{1}\leq Y\right)^{n}$

so that:

$\mathbb{E}N_{Y}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left(N_{Y}\geq n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left(X_{1}\leq Y\right)^{n}=\frac{P\left(X_{1}\leq Y\right)}{1-P\left(X_{1}\leq Y\right)}$

Now it remains to prove that $P\left(X_{1}\leq Y\right)=\mathbb{E}e^{-\lambda X_{1}}$.

Can you do that yourself?